# OS X PYTHONPATH for QGIS Standalone Apps?

Tags: qgis, python, osx

What's the correct PYTHONPATH for OS X and QGIS 3.4? I want to make a QGIS standalone app but get the "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qgis'" error. This happens after following the OS X instructions at the end of [Setting PythonPath](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139818/setting-pythonpath).

OS X 10.11.6
QGIS 3.4.4
Python 3.6.8

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/Resources/python:${PYTHONPATH}
```

Substitute whatever version of QGIS you are running of course.